# Is the floor function defined for complex values?

Tags: complex-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I was working on a problem which involved the usage of the [Floor Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)(Or the greatest integer function) and a question came to my mind,

> Is the floor function defined for complex values?

More precisely, Is $$\lfloor x+iy \rfloor$$ defined?

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor%28a%2Bib%29) says that it equals $\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor i$ but I doubt if that's true

My thought was that the floor function isn't defined for the complex values because it returns an **integer less than or equal to the number inside the floor** so it isn't defined. Another question,

Can we define $\lfloor x + iy \rfloor = x+iy$ ?

Any hint/answer is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on your definition of a floor function. Mathematica has a definition that extends integers to gaussian integers. You may dislike it and have it undefined.

Comment: wdym? $\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor y\rfloor i$ _is_ a gaussian integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inequality is indeed not defined for complex numbers.

A possible extension of the definition of the floor function, is to apply it to each of the components of the complex number. Or one step further, to apply it so that we get a [Gaussian integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer). Yet another alternative is to apply it to the magnitude.

In the first case we have $\lfloor 1.6+1.7i\rfloor = \lfloor 1.6\rfloor+\lfloor 1.7\rfloor i = 1+i$.
In the second case we might have $\lfloor 1.6+1.7i\rfloor = \frac 32+\frac 32 i$.
In the third case we get $\lfloor 1.6+1.7i\rfloor=\lfloor |1.6+1.7i|\rfloor=\lfloor\sqrt{1.6^2+1.7^2}\rfloor$.

Up to you how to define it, or leave it undefined.

Comment: Answered my question... Thanks